# Why does react code not display after declaring state variables?

Tags: reactjs

Ive never had this issue before so this is kind of weird. I have a react component in which there is some code rendered on the screen, but once i declare state variables using this.state={} nothing displays and it just ends up being a blank screen. ive tried changing the component from a const to a class but still get the same result which is a blank screen.

Here is my react component code:

```js
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from './assets/logo.png';


const ClaimApproval = () => {

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const onclick = () => {
        navigate("/mainpageLM")
    }
    this.state={
        claim1: true,
        claim1state: "Pending",
        claim2: true,
        claim2state: "Pending",
        claim3: true,
        claim3state: "Pending",
        claim4: true,
        claim4state: "Pending",
    };
    

    return (
        <>
            <div className="formpage">
                <a onClick={onclick}><img className="logoForm" src={logo}></img></a>
                <h1 className='form-title'>Manager Approval</h1>
                <form className="form" class='center' align='middle'>
                    <fieldset text-align='center'>
                        <table class='center'>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Amount</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>File</th>
                                <th>Approve/Deny</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Amy Darwin</th>
                                <th>$12.75</th>
                                <th>Approved</th>
                                <th>Claim.pdf</th>
                                <th><button type="approve" className="submitbutton" >Approve</button></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>James Peters</th>
                                <th>$34.34</th>
                                <th>Pending</th>
                                <th>expense_claim.pdf</th>
                                <th><button type="approve" className="submitbutton">Approve</button></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Arch Mathis</th>
                                <th>$45.32</th>
                                <th>Approved</th>
                                <th>claim12.pdf</th>
                                <th><button type="approve" className="submitbutton">Approve</button></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Mark Collins</th>
                                <th>$23.45</th>
                                <th>Approved</th>
                                <th>claim.pdf</th>
                                <th><button type="approve" className="submitbutton">Approve</button></th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </fieldset>
                    
                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    )

}

export default ClaimApproval;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare state variables using the `useState` hook in your functional component.

read: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html